# MongoDB find by date in Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Schema:

```
var Users = mongoose.Schema({name: String, usersearchcontractors: [UserSearchcontractors]}


var UserSearchcontractors = new mongoose.Schema({
    type:{ type:String,index:  true },
    area: { type:String,index:  true },
    createdate: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
    });
```

Query:

```
db.users.find( { usersearchcontractors: { $elemMatch: { createdate: { "$lt": new Date()} } } } )
```

What i'm doing wrong to get users by usersearchcontractors.createdate ?

No results

Thank,

Ron

Answer (score 0):

No need to use $elemMatch for this query.

```
db.users.find( { 'usersearchcontractors.createdate': { "$lt": new Date() } } )
```